# How to get file with greatest number in filename within directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Consider I have a directory with the following files:

```
20151203073208_create_animals.rb
20151214130905_create_spoons.rb
20151230083444_create_cups.rb
20160226120137_create_humans.rb
20160321204759_create_trees.rb
```

I need to get these digits **20160321204759**.

However finding the last modified file doesn't apply here as any file withing the directory can be modified last.

For example:

```
Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('db/migrate/**.*')).max_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}
```

produces

```
20151214130905_create_spoons.rb
```

So how can I get number from filename with the greatest digits?

Comment: Might the directory containing those files contain other files as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find all migrations:

```
Dir['db/migrate/**/[0-9]*_*.rb']
#=> ["20151203073208_create_animals.rb",
#    "20151214130905_create_spoons.rb",
#    "20151230083444_create_cups.rb",
#    "20160226120137_create_humans.rb",
#    "20160321204759_create_trees.rb"]
```

The one with the largest timestamp:

```
Dir['db/migrate/**/[0-9]*_*.rb'].max
#=> "20160321204759_create_trees.rb"
```

Just the timestamp:

```
Dir['db/migrate/**/[0-9]*_*.rb'].max[/\d+/]
#=> "20160321204759"
```

Of course, you can also use `Dir.glob` instead of `Dir.[]` and `Rails.root` instead of a relative path name.

Comment: 'Just the timestamp' could alternatively be `...max[0,14]`.

Answer (score 1):

A super basic way of doing this (not necessarily the most efficient) would be something like this:

```
Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('db/migrate/**.*')).max_by {|f| f.split('/').last.split('_').first}
```

Comment: I'm digging your answer, however, frankly I don't know how fast it is.

Comment: You can simply call `Dir.glob(...).max`, there's no need to split the filename.

Comment: @Stefan It's absolutely neat. Can you create an answer? But, in addition, I need to fetch specifically numbers and not full filename itself.

Comment: Totally prefaced that it wasn't efficient, it was a quick answer.  @Stefan's is definitely preferable.